# Game Center Player Photos in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

i want to apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this but i have a problem with setting a game center profile pic, and because of this i can't test the code.
i looked in settings/ game center/ profile but there is not a way to set up avatar photo.

the code in question is this:

```
player.loadPhoto(forSize: .min, withCompletionHandler: {(photo: UIImage?, error: Error?) -> Void in
                            if !(error != nil) {
                                let playerImage = UIImageView()
                                playerImage.image! = photo!
                                Constants.playerPhoto = playerImage.image!
                            }
                            else {
                                print("Error loading image")
                                Constants.playerPhoto = UIImage(named: "userPhoto.png")!
                            }
                        })
```

and i'll appreciate if someone take a look and can find some kind of error.

edit: i see i wasn't clear, so the main question is: Is there a way to set up a new game center avatar photo?

Comment: You can try this approaches: Ask user for third party login (facebook, google) and get the photo from there. As an alternative, ask user for uploading a photo and create a small service for hosting photos.

Comment: @ThorstenC I abandoned the Game Center implementation, now I'm giving a try to firebase and am implementing a Facebook login. I did it, because it seems apple don't allow us to link a Game Center with other type of accounts (i.e. Facebook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Game Center photos were killed server-side.